# How to read all strings of a certain length into shell variables named sequentially?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bitcoin

I was wondering if there was code to find every string of a certain length in a text file and save each one as a new variable?

For example, there are 5 strings in a text file. Two of them are 3 characters long. The idea is to parse out all the strings which are 8 characters long and put them in variables going in sequential order, e.g. `var1`, `var2`, `var3`.

How would I make this?

Thanks!

(For those wondering, I found an old file on my PC with a bunch of bitcoin wallets with private keys, trying to save them all as variables to check their balances.)

To view more info on bitcoin addresses, and to see what characters they consist of, visit the website on bitcoin addresses [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you try to achieve / what problem you try to solve? I've the feeling there might be a more elegant solution

Comment: You'd be much better served by adding them to an _array_.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "string". `"That's a 24-byte String!"`. What characters are excluded -- blanks, punctuation, numerics, non-ascii? Do you mean words, including UTF-8 characters like Cyrillic or Greek?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using an alphabetized list of all the unique 8-letter words in `man bash`:

```
bash   # clean temporary environment 
. <(man bash | tr -sc '[[:alpha:]]' '\n' |
    egrep  '^[a-z]{8}$' | sort -u | 
    nl -s '=' | sed 's/^ */var/')
echo $var20 $var80 $var200
```

Output:

```
asterisk document precedes
```

To clean up, do:

```
exit   # forget all those vars
```

---

Notes:

- Make absolutely sure the input data more or less *inert*, and doesn't contain anything dangerous the shell might accidentally interpret as commands.  If it does, the assignments can't safely be done with `=`, and must use something more sensible like `printf -v var1 foobar`.
- The `man bash` example is more complex than this Q. requires.  The main thing is `nl` to add number and `=`, and `sed` to prefix the stream with `var`, then `.` to run it and thus assign strings to variables.